# Unknown bug in printing string in c

Tags: c, string, input

I am writing a code for checking inputs 
now what i need to do is to check if the user typed "read_set a" ...
but it doesn't matter what i want to do ..

If the input is : "read_seta,123" , it displays with **no BUGS**
If the input is : "read_set a,123" , it displays with **BUGS**

code is :

```
     input[100];
     scanf("%s",input);
     printf("%s",input);
        read_set(input)

int read_set(char input[]){
    printf("%c\n\n",input[8]);
    printf("%s",input);
}
```

in the **first** printf , i want the code to display the **space** " " but it doesn't
and instead it keep printing strange character everytime (everytime **random** character)

and also the **second** printf doesn't display at all

what is the problem ?

Comment: Your scanf is reading "read_set", and when you try to access index 10, it's undefined. I.E. You only read in 1 string at a time, if you want to read in "read_set a" you need to read in a string, and then a character and append it to the string with a space before it. Even then, that's only 10 characters, so accessing index 10 is still undefined (index 9 will contain 'a')

Comment: @WaseemGabour Indeed, your problem is that `scanf()` doesn't do what you think it does. Generally, you should avoid that horrible function altogether. For getting user input line by line, consider using `fgets()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
change scanf("%s", input); to scanf("%14c", input);
```

Now the problem is that scanf needs 14 characters otherwise it want return.
So for the input string "**read_set a,123**" it works fine but for lets say "**read_set**"
it needs 6 more characters(including '**\n**').

valter

Answer (score 0):

`"%s"` does not save spaces.

`scanf("%s",input);` only reads `"read_set a,123"` up to `"read_set"`.

To read the entire line recommend:

```
fgets(input, sizeof input, stdin);
// To trim trailing \n
size_t len = strlen(input);
if (len > 0 && input[len-1] == '\n') input[--len] = '\0';
printf("%s", input);
```